# I made setprefix with js and it has an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord music bot that has many features. I made a `setprefix` command that worked so perfect first, then `help` has an error. The error is:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I am not sure what to do can anyone help me?

`help.js`:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    info: {
        name: "help",
        description: "To show all commands",
        usage: "[command]",
        aliases: ["commands", "help me", "pls help"]
    },

    execute(client, message, args){
        var allcmds = "";

        client.commands.forEach(cmd => {
            let cmdinfo = cmd.info
            allcmds+="``"+message.client.prefix+cmdinfo.name+" "+cmdinfo.usage+"`` ~ "+cmdinfo.description+"\n"
        })

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Commands of "+client.user.username, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SudhanPlayz/Discord-MusicBot/master/assets/Music.gif")
        .setColor("BLUE")
        .setDescription(allcmds)
        .setFooter(`To get info of each command you can do ${client.config.prefix}help [command] and my prefix is % | Hander by Lavaboy0192#2014`)

        if(!args[0])return message.channel.send(embed)
        else {
            let cmd = args[0]
            let command = client.commands.get(cmd)
            if(!command)command = client.commands.find(x => x.info.aliases.includes(cmd))
            if(!command)return message.channel.send("Unknown Command")
            let commandinfo = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Command: "+command.info.name+" info")
            .setColor("YELLOW")
            .setDescription(`
Name: ${command.info.name}
Description: ${command.info.description}
Usage: \`\`${client.config.prefix}${command.info.name} ${command.info.usage}\`\`
Aliases: ${command.info.aliases.join(", ")}
`)
            message.channel.send(commandinfo)
        }
    }
}
```

The setprefix command:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "setprefix",
    description: "Sets the prefix for the bot",
    argsNumber: 1,
    usage: "<prefix>",
    execute(message, args){
        const prefix = args.shift();
        message.client.prefixes.set(message.guild.id, prefix);
        message.reply(`Prefix set to ${prefix}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

module.exports is placed wrong, module.exports should be in the directory from where you are going to export, if I am correct about your code.

Example:-

```
answer.js:- module.exports = {
'value': {
    name: "setprefix",
    description: "Sets the prefix for the bot",
    argsNumber: 1,
    usage: "<prefix>",
    execute(message, args){
        const prefix = args.shift();
        message.client.prefixes.set(message.guild.id, prefix);
        message.reply(`Prefix set to ${prefix}`);
}
```

```
index.js:- const answer = require(./answer)

message.channel.send("Name:- $(answer.name) \n argsNumber:- $(answer.argsNumber)") //etc....
```

**If I am wrong:-**

1.Can you please also tell in which directory is your command?

2.Can you tell why did you do module.exports in that directory?

3.Try To point out exact reason or line of error.

*please tell me about that in comment...*

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no `info` property on your exported module. Judging by the export in your `help.js` file your other command files export an object with two keys; `info` and `execute`.

In the `execute` method in your `help.js` you iterate over `client.commands` and for every command you try to get the `info` property (`let cmdinfo = cmd.info`). As there is no `info` prop for your `setprefix` command, `cmdinfo` will be undefined. On the next line, you try to get `cmdinfo.name`, `cmdinfo.usage`, and `cmdinfo.description` but as it can't read the property `name`, it throws a *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"*.

Try to run the snippet below, it will throw the same error:

```js
let cmd = {
  name: 'setprefix',
  description: 'Sets the prefix for the bot',
  argsNumber: 1,
  usage: '<prefix>',
  execute: {},
};

let cmdinfo = cmd.info;

console.log(cmdinfo.name);
```

To fix this, you need to add a new `info` object and move everything except `execute` inside it like in the following snippet. Try to run it, you can see that it prints the `name` properly:

```js
let cmd = {
  info: {
    name: 'setprefix',
    description: 'Sets the prefix for the bot',
    argsNumber: 1,
    usage: '<prefix>',
  },
  execute: {},
};

let cmdinfo = cmd.info;

console.log(cmdinfo.name);
```

You also need to add an array with the key `aliases`, even if there is none as your code above tries to find them too. Here is your final code.

```js
module.exports = {
  info: {
    name: 'setprefix',
    description: 'Sets the prefix for the bot',
    argsNumber: 1,
    usage: '<prefix>',
    aliases: [],
  },
  execute(message, args) {
    const prefix = args.shift();
    message.client.prefixes.set(message.guild.id, prefix);
    message.reply(`Prefix set to ${prefix}`);
  },
};
```

Comment: theres an error ```TypeError: args.shift is not a function
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/Rayong/commands/setprefix.js:9:25)```

Comment: Have you checked what `args` is? Have you tried to log what it is? Is it an array? Have you passed it to your `execute` function in the main file? In the other file it's `execute(client, message, args){...`. Do you pass `message` as the second argument to every `execute` method?

Comment: I have a little thing aliases is not working

Comment: I've updated my code. You need to add an `aliases` array to your `info`, even if it's just an empty array.